# Python 3.5 - Pandas - Call a method with a for loop from another method

Tags: python, pandas

Background:

I'm using Python 3.5 with Pandas and Jupyter Notebook. This is my first go at
classes. Working with the Jupyter Notebook one can simply run small bits of 
code one cell at a time. I'd like to start making
scripts/programs that have a logical and more readably flow. But there are
basics that I just don't understand yet. Know that I've spend a lot of time the last few days 
reading and trying things to get this to work. I rarely ask questions on SO
because I can usually get what I need from previous posts...like most people
I'm sure.

For some reason I'm just not getting how to do what I'm sure is simple. Below
is a snippet from a large program I'm writing. There are at this time four methods
and they are duplicate the same bit of code. And that is to loop
through the state_list in order to filter the states I want from the Pandas
dataframe that I'm reading in. Each method's purpose is to read in a different
file (xlsx and csv) and pull out data for a date and specific states.

Rather than repeating the for loop for in each method, can I
make it a method and then just call it from the other methods? I tried a few
things but it's just happening.

Current Code:

```
class GetData(object):

    report_date = '3/1/2016'
    state_list = ['AL', 'AZ', 'GA', 'IA', 'ID', 'IL', 'MN', 'MS', 
                  'MT', 'NE', 'NM', 'NV', 'TN', 'UT', 'WI']


def data_getter(self):
    """Pulls in dataset and filters on specific date and states."""

    data = pd.read_excel('C:\\datapath\\file.xlsx')
    data = data[data['date'] == GetData.report_date]

    states = []
    for state in GetData.state_list:
        df = data[data['state'] == state]
        states.append(df)
    concat_data = pd.concat(states, axis=0)
    return concat_data
```

Then I instantiate it like:

```
data = GetData()
dataset = data.data_getter()
```

Goal - soemthing like this?

```
class GetData(object):

    report_date = '3/1/2016'
    state_list = ['AL', 'AZ', 'GA', 'IA', 'ID', 'IL', 'MN', 'MS', 
                  'MT', 'NE', 'NM', 'NV', 'TN', 'UT', 'WI']


    def data_getter(self):
        """Pulls in dataset and filters on specific date and states."""

        data = pd.read_excel('C:\\datapath\\file.xlsx')
        data = data[data['date'] == GetData.report_date]

        # Call to state_filter here?

        data = GetData()
        data = data.state_filter

    def state_filter(self):
        states = []
        for state in GetData.state_list:
            df = data[data['state'] == state]
            states.append(df)
        concat_data = pd.concat(states, axis=0)
        return concat_data
```

Comment: you can try it this way instead of looping: `return data[data.state.isin(GetData.state_list)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

well you can always write your own wrapper class, but i would say there must be a good reason for that...

```
class GetData(object):

    #report_date = '3/1/2016'
    states = ['AL', 'AZ', 'GA', 'IA', 'ID', 'IL', 'MN', 'MS', 
              'MT', 'NE', 'NM', 'NV', 'TN', 'UT', 'WI']

    def __init__(self, df_or_file=None, read_func=pd.read_excel, **kwargs):
        if df_or_file is not None:
            if isinstance(df_or_file, (pd.DataFrame, pd.Series, pd.Panel)):
                self.data = df
            elif(os.path.isfile(df_or_file)):
                self.data = read_func(df_or_file, **kwargs)
        else:
            self.data = pd.DataFrame()

    def save(self, filename, savefunc=pd.DataFrame.to_excel, **kwargs):
        savefunc(df, filename, **kwargs)
```

now you can do the following things :

let's generate some random DF and prepare CSV and Excel files:

```
In [53]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(5, 3)), columns=list('abc'))

In [54]: df
Out[54]:
   a  b  c
0  6  0  2
1  8  1  5
2  5  5  4
3  0  4  1
4  5  4  2

In [55]: df.to_csv('d:/temp/test.csv', index=False)

In [56]: (df+100).to_excel('d:/temp/test.xlsx', index=False)
```

now we can create our object:

```
In [57]: x = GetData(df)

In [58]: x.data
Out[58]:
   a  b  c
0  6  0  2
1  8  1  5
2  5  5  4
3  0  4  1
4  5  4  2
```

or load it from CSV

```
In [61]: x = GetData('d:/temp/test.csv', read_func=pd.read_csv, sep=',')

In [62]: x.data
Out[62]:
   a  b  c
0  6  0  2
1  8  1  5
2  5  5  4
3  0  4  1
4  5  4  2

In [63]: x.data[x.data.a == 5]
Out[63]:
   a  b  c
2  5  5  4
4  5  4  2
```

or load it from Excel file:

```
In [64]: x = GetData('d:/temp/test.xlsx')

In [65]: x.data
Out[65]:
     a    b    c
0  106  100  102
1  108  101  105
2  105  105  104
3  100  104  101
4  105  104  102
```

and save it:

```
In [66]: x.data.c = 0

In [67]: x.data
Out[67]:
     a    b  c
0  106  100  0
1  108  101  0
2  105  105  0
3  100  104  0
4  105  104  0

In [68]: x.save('d:/temp/new.xlsx', index=False)

In [69]: x.save('d:/temp/new.csv', savefunc=pd.DataFrame.to_csv, sep=';', index=False)
```

Comment: return data[data.state.isin(GetData.state_list)] does work. But if I wanted use the state_filter method you describe how would I call it from the other methods?

Comment: @Shane, are you trying to write your own small pandas module?

Comment: Not necessarily. I'm trying to be better Python "programmer" by using classes and methods versus using multiple cells to transform Pandas dataframes. The multi-cell approach just looks messy and if you have a lot of 'em it can be difficult to follow without reviewing every single cell. If you merge all of the cells and paste into an IDE or text editor it's just one big blob of code. So I'm starting a little at a time converting to classes. I've been looking at codereview to see how others implement this but it doesn't really look like they're used much with Pandas. Overkill?

Comment: @Shane CR would be fine.  Probably *somebody* has used it.

Comment: @maxu thanks for your time on this. I've seen reference to wrapper classes before but wasn't sure how to make or use them. Per your comment "but i would say there must be a good reason for that..." I'm going to play with this a bit to figure out how best to use it for my situation. At the very least it should help educate me. Appreciate your time and effort.